# Is it possible to share a database through google drive / one drive and use it on a form application?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm currently an intern on a company that needs me to create a program that can manage some client information. They want me to use their Google Drive / OneDrive shared folder (I can't remember which one, but I think its most likely going to work the same way) to store the database that's going to hold all the information.

My question is, is it possible to connect to, let's say an access database inside that shared folder and use it inside a windows form application? If so, how would I do it? I have not that much experience with SQL, but I only need to add, remove and edit data, so it's nothing complex, I just need to know how to make the connection.

I know that if it is possible users can't use the program at the same time, but that wouldn't be a problem since they are familiar with that.

Comment: Also review https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_other-msoversion_other/access-2013-split-database-with-backend-on-one/c36dafc5-7428-43f3-a7d1-78095629109f?auth=1

Comment: @June7 Yeah, I guess it does. Looks like I can't so I'm going to have to look for another solution, thanks!